# how to checkout a specific commit from git

Tags: git, bitbucket

My code isn't working and it seems I have merged a wrong piece of code in my `master` branch. I am unable to pin point the issue and thus I want to pull specific commits one by one to find out which version was working just before the wrong commit.

How could I pull a specific commit? Eg, On Bitbucket, I see a merge with id `9ce920d` on branch `test` but I don't know how to pull this merge.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The question has wrong terminology. You cannot pull a commit, you can only checkout a commit. Pulling a commit would defy the whole branch/commit structure saving memory. You pull all commits in a branch or repository, and if you want to check out a specific one, then well, check it out:

```
git checkout 9ce920d
```

You will be in headless mode (no pointer to the commit, even if you have branches pointing to them - you have to check them out explicitly!), so you may want to create a branch if you want to mess around:

```
git checkout -B mess_around_branch
```

For posterity, OP actually wanted to discard all commits from the latest commit on their branch to a specific commit before. To do this from your branch hit:

```
git reset 9ce920d
```

which will discard all commits, but leave the files as they were, allowing you to decide if you wish to retain some of the changes. If you really want to lose everything:

```
git reset --hard 9ce920d
```

Comment: Thanks. And how could I discard this checkout? I mean, say I find the issue which is several commits before the latest one. I would prefer to then discard this checkout and checkout from latest version. Do I just do another checkout with latest merge id?

Comment: @ManuChadha Either start a branch from there and work, or on the branch you want to fix `git reset --hard 9ce920d~1` will move the branch one below (you can also specify the commit). This is dangerous though - you will be discarding all commits above it.

Answer (score 6):

```
git checkout <id>
```

should do the trick. Where 'id' is the specific commit you want to get.